# Use type of self as function parameter in extension

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'd like to write a function via extension, let's say on `UIView`. That function should have a parameter of the same type as the object that gets the function called on e.g. a `UIButton` or `UIImageView` that can be used in the block implementation and of course with its actual type.

As always, code may explain best:

```
extension UIView {
    func performOnMe<T>(_ block: (_ obj: T) -> Void) -> T {
        block(self)
        return self
    }
}

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
button.performOnMe { $0.alpha = 1 }
      .performOnMe { $0.setTitle("Title", for: .normal) }
      .performOnMe { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.red }

let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
image.performOnMe { $0.alpha = 1 }
     .performOnMe { $0.image = nil }
```

Of course that snippet does not compile because Swift can not infer the type of T. And that's the challange. How would I solve that? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You probably meant `UIImageView` in the second example ...

Comment: You are right, sorry, mistyped that in the StackOverflow editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "trick" is to define a protocol  with a default implementation
in an extension, and make `UIView` conform to that protocol:

```
protocol PerformOnMe { }

extension PerformOnMe {
    @discardableResult func performOnMe(_ block: (Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        block(self)
        return self
    }
}

extension UIView: PerformOnMe {}
```

The `@discardableResult` attribute is added to avoid an
"expression result is unused" warning in the calling chain:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
button.performOnMe { $0.alpha = 1 }
    .performOnMe { $0.setTitle("Title", for: .normal) }
    .performOnMe { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.red }

let imageView = UIImageView()
image.performOnMe { $0.alpha = 1 }
    .performOnMe { $0.image = nil }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's pretty much what I was looking for. I just thought that an extension+generics was enough.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to extend a specific subclass of UIView?

In that case I recommend you define a protocol and extend the classes you wish with it, like so:

```
protocol Perform {}

// This extension is only available to UIViews (you can replace with Any or AnyObject to have it available on everything or all objects)
extension Perform where Self: UIView {

    func performOnMe(_ block: (Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        block(self)
        return self
    }

}

// Apply protocol to all UIViews
extension UIView: Perform {}

// Usage
UIView().performOnMe { (view) in
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach that will work with any object, not only UIViews

```
infix operator <~: AdditionPrecedence

@discardableResult public func <~ <T>(obj: T, block: (T) -> ()) -> T {
    block(obj)
    return obj
}

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
    <~ { $0.alpha = 1 }
    <~ { $0.setTitle("Title", for: .normal) }
    <~ { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.red }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that suggestion. A complete different way to solve that. I would have never thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this for all classes using an operator:

```
infix operator <-< : AdditionPrecedence 
func <-<<T>(left:T, right:(T)->()) -> T
{
  right(left)
  return left
}

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
             <-< { $0.alpha = 0.3 }
             <-< { $0.setTitle("Title", for: .normal) }
             <-< { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue }

or 

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero) <-< { 
                $0.alpha = 0.3      
                $0.setTitle("Title", for: .normal) 
                $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue 
             }
```